# Failed to redirect page in a Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

As per title above, I am using CodeIgniter as the MVC framework.

```
function langpref($lang=''){
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['cur_lang'] = 'abc123';

    echo $_SESSION['cur_lang'];

    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
```

it stuck at the page and print the session value instead of redirect to google.com.

Answer (score 0):

`header`s will not work if output begins before the header is sent. In this case, remove the `echo` before you send the header (and ensure that you're not `echo`ing or `print`ing anything else previously) and you should be ok:

```
function langpref($lang=''){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cur_lang'] = 'abc123';
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: Do you have any output elsewhere in your script? You can try calling `exit()` immediately after sending the header to ensure that nothing later on is executed.

Comment: Can you try removing *everything* from your controller function except the `header`? If it still doesn't work, the problem is elsewhere in your application.

Comment: alright, its working now after I remove the helper from my autoload.php

but problem now I need to runs the helper in order to get the function done.

Answer (score 0):

try this `redirect($url,'refresh')`

Answer (score 0):

Load the url helper then use redirect function. if you want to redirect on the same controller's function use `$this->function_name();`